# How to use href attributes to store meta data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a href tag that when clicked opens up a popup window.

I want to store additional information in the href tag so I can then fetch that from the popup window.

```
<a href="" class="js-stripe-button">Order</a>
```

If I want to store the following information, can i store in in the href tag itself?

```
amount
description
```

My jquery currently looks like:

```
$(".js-stripe-button").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var amount = ???
   var description = ???
}();
```

Is there a built-in way to get values from the clicked element?

Comment: better use `data-id`

Comment: fetch using what...script or server side code? Is popup on same domain? Numerous ways to do this depending on use case

Comment: Note, close of `.on()` should be `})` instead of `}()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and store "anything".

```
<a href="" class="js-stripe-button" data-amount="10" data-description="My Description">Order</a>
```

Then get it with [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```
var amount = element.dataset.amount;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why store it in the href when you can use a data attribute?

```
<a href="" data-amount="" data-description="" class="myThing">Order</a>
```

Then you can retrieve it like so...

```
var a = document.querySelector('.myThing');

var amount = a.dataset.amount;

var description = a.dataset.description;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate query string at `.href` of clicked element, call `window.open()` on string

```
$(".js-stripe-button").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var amount = ???
   var description = ???
   window.open(`${this.href}?amount=${amount}&description=${description}`);
});
```

Comment: At popup `window` use `location.search` to get query string